# Meteor: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am getting the following error

```
W20141210-18:14:54.394(5.5)? (STDERR) 
W20141210-18:14:54.395(5.5)? (STDERR) /Users/removed/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.36.1phxfod++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141210-18:14:54.395(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
W20141210-18:14:54.395(5.5)? (STDERR)                             ^
W20141210-18:14:54.396(5.5)? (STDERR) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

When I am using meteor methods to return a query result.

```
Meteor.methods({
    rquery: function(post){
        console.log(post);
        var result = AdvtColl.find();
        return result;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't return a cursor from a method - only [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ejson).  In your code, `result` is the result of a `find` call, which is a cursor - you need to either use `findOne` or add `fetch()` after the `find()` to return the document(s) in question.

```
var result = AdvtColl.findOne(); // RETURNS A DOCUMENT

var result = AdvtColl.find().fetch(); // RETURNS AN ARRAY OF DOCS (EVEN IF THERE'S ONLY ONE OF THEM)
```

Comment: Got it, only publish function can return a cursor. Thanks