# How to check if a mongoDB record is less than a day old?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to implement a user "group" system in my meteor application. Here is a simplified example of a group document mongodb structure :

```
{
    "_id": "w74grb7GnaoqS4dMJ", //Id of the group
    "name": "My beautiful group",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2015-05-27T12:44:52.288Z"),
    "createdBy": "7tKqK3bm72MK47ngH",
    "users": [
    "7tKqK3bm72MK47ngH" //Meteor user id array
    ],
    "admins": [
    "7tKqK3bm72MK47ngH"
    ],
    "leaving_users": [
    {
    "user_id": "9zXdV6bm72MK47ngH",
    "leaving_date": ISODate("2015-05-27T16:15:23.170Z")
    }],
    "modifiedAt": ISODate("2015-05-27T16:41:57.589Z"),
    "modifiedBy": "FZ78Pr82JPz66Gc3p"
}
```

I want to obtain the following behavior:

- When a user leave a group, his id is removed from the group "users" array.
- Since I want him to be able to re-join the group in the next 24h without requesting a validation by a group admin, I also create a "leaving_users" array of objects with 2 string fields: the userId and the date he left.
- If the user try to join again the recently left group within the 24h limit, I want to check if he belongs to the leaving_users array, and if his record is less than 24h days old.

The part I have trouble with is the server Method that send back a boolean flag meaning"has the user left in the past 24h". I guess it has to do with my mongo request but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here is my method code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    GroupRecentlyQuitted: function(groupId) {
    //groups left by current user in the past 24h
    if (Users.isInRoles(Meteor.userId(), ["user"])) {
        var yesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        return Groups.find({
            _id: groupId,
            "leaving_users.user_id": Meteor.userId(),
            "leaving_users.leaving_date": {
                $gte: yesterday
            }
        });
    }
    }
});
```

And the client side code where I call the method:

```
var RecentlyQuitted = false
Meteor.call("GroupRecentlyQuitted", me._id, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    }
    if (result) {
    RecentlyQuitted = true
    console.log(result);
    }
});
```

This version throws a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I don't get why neither do I know how to have a better feedback from my server method execution (the error occurs during the Group.find query in the method).

Edit: the query works fine in robomongo, when I input it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve this using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27402350/3793161) from @richsilv (if you read me, thank you dude). It turns out that you can't expect a cursor from a server Method (EJSON only), only publish provides a cursor. Three days to figure that out... :-)

To summarize it, you can't return a `Collection.find()` in a method (i.e. a cursor). You need to return the document using `Collection.findOne()` or an array of documents using `Collection.find().fetch()`